# What does it mean to lazily install a dependency

Tags: javascript, ember.js, npm, bower

On the following page (https://simplabs.com/blog/2017/02/13/npm-libs-in-ember-cli.html), it says;

> With Ember 2.11 we are now using the ember-source module and no longer
>   the ember Bower package. In the upcoming Ember CLI 2.12 release, Bower
>   will also no longer be installed by default and only install lazily
>   when an addon requests it.

I wanted to understand what does the following mean "only install lazily when an addon requests it" ?

Comment: That sentence seems slightly redundant in my opinion, but "lazy/lazily" in a programming sense generally means "at the time of request", i.e. it will only install if and when requested, rather than up-front/preemptively. I've chosen not to submit this as an answer in the event you're looking for something more specific to Ember/Bower that I can't speak to.

Comment: Lazy-loading contrasts eager-loading by only loading resources when they are needed versus an all-up-front approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this references to [this API](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Blueprint.html#method_addBowerPackagesToProject), which basically allows a `ember-cli` blueprint to install a bower package.

While this API probably should not be used because bower should not be used it's a quite old API. And it will now install a local `bower` (and so add `bower` to the `package.json`) and *then* add that bower package to `bower.json` and then call a `bower install`. This was not necessary before because all `ember-cli` projects already used `bower`.

Comment: Awesome. Quite close to what I am looking for..But just one follow up question...What do you mean when you say "it will now install a local bower"

Comment: loca as in `npm install bower`, not global as `npm install -g bower`. So it will be installed to `node_modules` and the binary is in `node_modules/.bin`. So it can be used from scripts inside `package.json` or with `npx`. However it won't be in your `PATH`.